# How to generate dynamic select box from object

Tags: reactjs, object, antd

I am trying to generate dynamic select box based on data getting from api.

Here is the object

```
{
    "profession": [{
        "id": 15,
        "name": "Sales/Marketing",
        "description": "Sales/Marketing"
    }, {
        "id": 16,
        "name": "Analyst",
        "description": "Analyst"
    }, {
        "id": 17,
        "name": "Doctor/Medical",
        "description": "Doctor/Medical"
    }],
    "education": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "10th",
        "description": ""
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "12th",
        "description": ""
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Diploma",
        "description": ""
    }],
    "profilestatus": [{
        "status_id": 1,
        "status_name": "some data",
        "status_message": "some data"
    }, {
        "status_id": 2,
        "status_name": "some data",
        "status_message": "some data"
    }, {
        "status_id": 3,
        "status_name": "some data",
        "status_message": "some data"
    }]
}
```

Here each key(Example: profession, education, profilestatus) in the object is a separate select box.
I am able to generate blank select box but option values are not passing. How do I pass options to particular Select box?

```
{
    Object.keys(CustomerAPI).map((key)=>{
        return(<Select

        options={key.map((select, i)=>{
            return select.name
        })}
        placeholder='some text'

        >
        </Select>)
    })
}
```

This gives me error stating key.map is not a function. 
Someone please help.

Comment: you want name from education and profession from both?

Comment: try `CustomerAPI[key].map(...)`

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = {
  "profession": [{
      "id": 15,
      "name": "Sales/Marketing",
      "description": "Sales/Marketing"
  }, {
      "id": 16,
      "name": "Analyst",
      "description": "Analyst"
  }, {
      "id": 17,
      "name": "Doctor/Medical",
      "description": "Doctor/Medical"
  }],
  "education": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "10th",
      "description": ""
  }, {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "12th",
      "description": ""
  }, {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Diploma",
      "description": ""
  }],
  "profilestatus": [{
      "status_id": 1,
      "status_name": "some data",
      "status_message": "some data"
  }, {
      "status_id": 2,
      "status_name": "some data",
      "status_message": "some data"
  }, {
      "status_id": 3,
      "status_name": "some data",
      "status_message": "some data"
  }]
}
let prof=data.profession;
let edu =data.education;
let arr = [...prof, ...edu];
```

if you want only profession

```
      <div>
       <h3>profession</h3>
       <select>
       {prof.map(pro=>
        <option key={pro.id} value={pro.name}>{pro.name}</option>
        )}
       </select>
      </div>
```

if you want profession and education both

```
      <div>
       <h3>Profession & Education</h3>
       <select>
       {arr.map(a=>
        <option key={a.id} value={a.name}>{a.name}</option>
        )}
       </select>
      </div>
```